# ActiveAdmin has_many through edit 1k records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, has-many-through

I have `has_many through` relationship setup between my model `Company` and `Group`. Here's the model code:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_groups
  has_many :groups, through: :company_groups

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_groups, allow_destroy: true
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_groups
  has_many :companies, through: :company_groups

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_groups, allow_destroy: true
end

class CompanyGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :group

  validates_uniqueness_of :company_id, :scope => :group_id
end
```

The problem I have is, in my `company_groups` table there are 900 records for `group_id=1`

Now, if I am giving option to edit the group, it tries to load all 900 records at one go.

Here's my `/app/admin/group.rb` file:

```
form do |f|
  return unless current_admin_user.super_admin?
  f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
  f.inputs 'Group Information' do
    f.input :name
  end
  f.has_many :company_groups do | company_group |
    if !company_group.object.nil?
      company_group.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean, :label => "Destroy?"
    end
    if company_group.object.new_record?
      company_group.input :company, :label => 'Company', :as => :select, :collection => @companies
    else
      company_group.input :company, :input_html => { :readonly => "readonly", :value => company_group.object.company.name }, :as => :string
    end
  end
  f.actions
end
```

The page was taking hell lot of time to load, so I have enabled the check, if `company_group` is not a new object, show the `company.name` in textbox (in readonly form). Though, this bring the page load time to < 25 seconds but I still think this is not a good practice to load these many records at once (as this could hang the browser as well)

I will bifurcate my question into 2 parts:

1. From optimisation perspective what would be the best way to edit those records (Search/Lazy loading etc)? And if anyone has done this thing earlier or similar kind of functionality, can you share code snippet to achieve
2. From ActiveAdmin perspective, does ActiveAdmin provides a convenient way to edit records in batches?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Best,
Puneet

**EDIT**: 05/Apr/17

Here's what I am doing to edit 1k records:

1. Allowing add|edit groups on Company new/edit pages.
2. Allowing add company to group via button on Group show/edit pages.
3. Allowing edit|delete company from group via Group show page.
4. **CODE: My model code for company will remain as-is**
5. **CODE: My model code for group will remain as-is**

Here is my full code snippet:

```
class CompanyGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :company_id, :scope => :group_id

  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :group

  before_save :ensure_settings

protected
  def ensure_settings
    errors.add(:field_name_2, "You are not allowed to change this field when #{company.boolean_field_name} is set to TRUE") and return false if company.boolean_field_name && field_name_2_changed?
  end
end
```

Here's my file `/app/admin/company.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register Company do
  form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors
    f.inputs do
      f.input :field_1
      f.input :boolean_field_name
      f.has_many :company_groups do | company_group |
        company_group.input :group
        company_group.input :field_name_2, as: :radio, collection: [ ['Yes', true], ['No', false] ]
      end
    end
  end

  show do
    row :field_1
    row :boolean_field_name
    panel "Groups" do
      table_for company.company_groups do
        column "Group Name" do | company_group |
          company_group.group.name
        end
        column "Field Name 2" do |company_group|
          company_group.group.field_name_2
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here's my file `/app/admin/group.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register Group do
  config.action_items[0] = ActiveAdmin::ActionItem.new :show, only: [:show, :edit] do
    link_to 'Add Company to Group', new_company_group_path(group_id: group.id)
  end

  form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
    f.inputs do
      f.input :name
      unless f.object.company_groups.any?
        f.has_many :company_groups do | company_group |
          company_group.input :company, as: :select
          company_group.field_name_2, as: :radio, collection: [ ['Yes', true], ['No', false] ]
        end
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end

  show do
    attributes_table do
      row :name
    end

    panel "Companies" do
      table_for group.company_groups do
        column "" do |company_group|
          link_to("Edit", edit_company_group_path(company_group, group_id: group.id)) + "&nbsp;|&nbsp;".html_safe + (link_to "Delete", company_group_path(company_group), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this company from this group?" })
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And finally my `/app/models/company_group.rb` file:

```
ActiveAdmin.register CompanyGroup do
  form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
    f.inputs do
      f.input :group
      f.input :company
      f.input :field_name_2, as: :radio, collection: [ ['Yes', true], ['No', false] ]
    end
  end

  controller do
    def create
      create! do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to(new_company_group_path(group_id: @company_group.group_id)) }
      end
    end

    def update
      update! do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to(group_path(@company_group.group)) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But now I am running to different issues:

1. My custom model validation for `company_group.rb` is not working. That means, whenever I am trying to create/update company record and `boolean_field_name` is set to `TRUE` and `field_name_2` gets changed, I am not getting (a) error message, (b) though updated value of `field_name_2` is not updating in DB but I am not even stopped on create/update action. It takes me back to the show page.
2. Same is the case when I am trying to update a edit `company_group` object (via Group show/edit page). I expect to stay on POST/PATCH page of company_group with error message but I am getting redirected. Is that because of customise actions for `create` and `update`?

**EDIT**: 05/Apr/17

I've even tried checking `valid?` for `company_group` record by:

```
def create
  create! do |format|
    if resource.valid?
      format.html { redirect_to(new_company_group_path(group_id: @company_group.group_id)) }
    end
  end
end

def update
  if resource.valid?
    update! do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(group_path(@company_group.group)) }
    end
  end
end
```

But no luck!

Here're the logs:

```
Started PATCH "/company_groups/877" for ::1 at 2017-04-05 16:51:41 +0530
Processing by CompanyGroupsController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"T7jMdOHQygqiX5RSsEkfD1l0h5Q+dpaNrmJlhtiPhpaxen6AyBcv4yD7xAy2GefYpGX0Bvgx4oD7vTMsfIl6fw==", "company_group"=>{"group_id"=>"6", "company_id"=>"623", "field_name_2"=>"true"}, "commit"=>"Update Company group", "id"=>"877"}
[1m[36mCompanyGroup Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "company_groups".* FROM "company_groups" WHERE "company_groups"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 877]]
[1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  BEGIN
[1m[36mCompanyGroup Exists (0.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "company_groups" WHERE ("company_groups"."company_id" = 623 AND "company_groups"."id" != 877 AND "company_groups"."group_id" = 6) LIMIT 1[0m
[1m[35mCompany Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1  ORDER BY companies.name LIMIT 1  [["id", 623]]
[1m[36m (0.3ms)[0m  [1mROLLBACK[0m
[1m[35mCompanyGroup Exists (0.5ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "company_groups" WHERE ("company_groups"."company_id" = 623 AND "company_groups"."id" != 877 AND "company_groups"."group_id" = 6) LIMIT 1
[1m[36mGroup Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 6]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/superadmin/groups/6
Completed 302 Found in 94ms (ActiveRecord: 7.8ms)
```

Comment: And you add/remove a company each time you open this form?

Comment: I am open for any suggestion. 1 thing I can think to do is.. allow an edit link on group `show` action, that will lead user to edit the `has_many through` object
But if that was not accepted then:
- Is there a way I can edit a `company_group` object on group show action?

Comment: sure you can, just add form there, but if you have 1k records.... even hard to display them. to speed up showing the view you can add ajax with pagination to display, which is not good for editing

Comment: One thing I can add more into the solution list is to add inline editing of the record. For e.g. out of the list of 1000 records, if user wants to edit 100th record -> they click on edit -> the respective row will convert into edit form -> user makes adjustments to it -> Save
Are you aware of such JS library (compatible with ActiveAdmin) that does this?

Comment: But if user wants to add a new company into a group, then how would they do it? I came across this `best_in_place` gem but don't know, if it handles new action as well?

Comment: But it is easy to add, just add combobox for group in company edit form

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I get it resolved by changing the `before_save` callback to `validate`. The updated post from 5th/Apr will continue to remain same the only change I did is in `/app/models/company_group.rb` file.

```
class CompanyGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :company_id, :scope => :group_id

  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :group

  validate :ensure_settings

protected
  def ensure_settings
    errors.add(:field_name_2, "You are not allowed to change this field when #{company.boolean_field_name} is set to TRUE") and return false if company.boolean_field_name && field_name_2_changed?
  end
end
```

That's it. Thanks to one of my friend for suggesting me this. :)